# Comparing tables in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 tables, one is `Orders`, that holds the address/list of products, and a `returnDetails` table. This is used when a user wants to return an Order. The returnDetails has the OrderId that is being returned.

How do I display a message only on the orders that have a return with the same OrderID? Currently only "processing" is displayed.

I used a view model to display the Orders with products.
Here is what I tried but I haven't got it working yet:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(string date)
{
    string currentUser = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();

    List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.MyOrdersViewModel> list = (from o in new TshirtStoreDB().Orders
            .Where(o => o.Username == currentUser)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
            .Select(o => new MyOrdersViewModel()
            {
                OrderId = o.OrderId,
                Address = o.Address,
                FirstName = o.FirstName,
                LastName = o.LastName,
                City = o.City,
                OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
                Total = o.Total,
                HasBeenShipped = o.HasBeenShipped,
               PostageList = o.PostageList,
               Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                          select new MyOrderDetails
                          {
                              Colour = d.Product.Colour,
                              Quantity = d.Quantity,
                              Title = d.Product.Title,
                              UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                          }).ToList()
            }).ToList() select o).ToList();


    if (date != null)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(date) * -1);
        return View(list.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= today).ToList());
    }


     //WORKING ON
        var returnstats = db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == x.returnDetails.OrderId).ToList();
        if (returnstats != null)
        {
            ViewBag.returnstats = "Returning Item";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.returnstats = "processing";
        }


    return View(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not clear about what is the business logic for 'returnstats'. From the values of this variable you provide, it looks like it's for a SINGLE order instead of an order list. Here is a modified Index method for your reference:

```
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(Int32? days)
        {
            string currentUser = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();
            var orders = db.Orders  //assume db is something inherited from DbContext
                .Where(o => o.UserName == currentUser)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate);
            if (days.HasValue)
            {
                var startingDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays((-1) * days.Value);
                orders = orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= startingDate);
            }

            var orderList = orders.ToList();

            var returnOrderIds = db.ReturnDetails.Select(detail => detail.OrderId).ToList();

            //here you will need to check with business analyst staff what is the rule for 'returnstats'.
            //The business logic here is that if there is at least one order whose OrderId is in the ReturnDetails
            //the 'returnstats' is 'Returning Item' otherwise it's 'Processing'.
            if (orderList.Any(o => returnOrderIds.Contains(o.OrderId))
            {
                ViewBag.returnstats = "Returning Item";
            } else
            {
                ViewBag.returnstats = "processing";
            }

            var viewModels = ...//the source code to create Order ViewModel with variable orderList
            return View(viewModels);
        }
```